# Wordpress Multisite www non-www Page Redirect Failure

Tags: wordpress, redirect

My Wordpress Multisite is setup without the www. I was having an issue whenever I would add the www. i.e. www.domain.com/post-name/ would redirect me to domain.com.

I soon found out that it was because I removed the /blog/ part of the permalink structure in the super admin section for the site. The redirects were working fine again.

However the pages weren't. So whenever I accessed www.domain.com/page1 it would redirect back to domain.com

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

Remove the define('NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://www.domain.com'); from your wp-config file.

Add this in your htaccess file right under RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I didn't have a NOBLOGREDIRECT in my config file HOWEVER adding the conditions to my .htaccess worked like a charm thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your wp-config.php

```
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://domain.com' );
```

Comment: What the OP is describing is what happens when you add that code into the wp-config. He wants it to redirect but also keep the link /page1 instead of it getting dropped.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add any codes in htaccess file. There is very easy solution to this. In the 'Network Admin -> Settings -> Domains' page, add both the www. and non-www. versions of the domain, select the box of 'primary' for if you want to mainly use for www. or non-www. and both will be assigned to the website.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points so I'm posting this as an answer instead of a comment to where I got the solution from.

I added the following code into wp-config.php and while it wasn't used for its intended use, it still worked to solve my 'WP Multisite non-www redirect to www' issue.

define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://example.com' );

Comment: This sounds like a repeat of / thank-you to [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6380604).